# Why the directories-files do not have the 777 privileges when I gave that on the parent directory?

Tags: linux, terminal, fedora

There is a directory named `Joomla` inside `/opt/lampp/htdocs` directory. As I created the directory, first thing I did was to change its mode as :

```
[root@Feddy htdocs]# chmod 777 Joomla
```

Then I unzipped a *zip* file into the `Joomla` directory :

```
unzip -d /opt/lampp/htdocs/Joomla zipfile.zip
```

but when I check the privileges for the directories/files under the Joomla directory whose access I changed it to `777`,it returns :

```
[root@Feddy Joomla]# ls -l 
total 124
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 administrator
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 bin
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 cache
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 cli
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 components
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   823 Feb  4 05:35 CONTRIBUTING.md
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  3118 Feb  4 05:35 htaccess.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 images
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 includes
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1544 Feb  4 05:35 index.php
drwxr-xr-x. 10 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 installation
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1889 Feb  4 05:40 joomla.xml
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 language
drwxr-xr-x.  3 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 layouts
drwxr-xr-x.  9 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 libraries
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root 17816 Feb  4 05:35 LICENSE.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 logs
drwxr-xr-x. 16 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 media
drwxr-xr-x. 26 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 modules
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   871 Feb  4 05:35 phpunit.xml.dist
drwxr-xr-x. 13 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 plugins
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  4340 Feb  4 05:35 README.txt
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root   865 Feb  4 05:35 robots.txt
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 templates
drwxr-xr-x.  2 root root  4096 Feb  4 05:35 tmp
-rw-r--r--.  1 root root  1715 Feb  4 05:35 web.config.txt
```

while for`Joomla` directory I get :

```
drwxrwxrwx. 19 root      root       4096 Mar 14 20:42 Joomla
```

Why does the files-directories inside the `Joomla` directory do not have the same privilege as the directory `Joomla` itself ? How can I give each directory-file inside the `Joomla` directory the `777` privilege ?

Comment: Off subject, but 777 perms for any web served directory is a bad idea. If the machine ever gets compromised for any account level, I can put malware into your htdocs dir and try to compromise any web browsers that access it. These should be tightened up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the file/directory permissions do not get inherited. They get set according to the `umask` for every new one created. You can change the `umask` or run recursive `chmod -R` after you done creating all new folders you need.

Comment: like `chmod -R 777 Joomla` ?

Comment: yes. you need to be in `/opt/lampp/htdocs/` or just run `chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp/htdocs/Joomla`

Answer (score 0):

Because when you applied the permission the files were not in the the directory yet (and you didn't use `chmod -R` option, so even if they were inside the permission wouldn't have been applied to them). New files are copied (or created) using the mask of the user that is copying. You can re-apply the permissions on the directory (with -R for recursive) using `chmod -R 777 joomla` or you can use ACLs.

With [ACL](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/setfacl1.html) you can define the permissions for the existent files and default permissions for new files in the directory.